# How to add a directive onto a node in an ng-repeat only once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a feature tour directive similar to something like joyride that works by adding a directive onto a DOM element that highlights that element during a user a walk through.  For example:

```
<button test-drive-step 
        test-drive-text="To activate your search click here" 
        test-drive-next-label="Next">Search</button>
```

My question is if I want to place this on a list of elements and point out a single element using this feature how could I do that?  For example if the node I wanted to place the test-drive-step directive on is in an ng-repeat how do I limit that directive to just one element out of items rather than all?

For example,

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" test-drive-step ...>{{item.name}}</item>
```

That would place the test-drive-step directive on every element in items, but I just want it on the first element.  How could I limit it to just the first element?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to pass in a conditional to the directive, telling it whether to apply itself.

For example we can use `$index === 0` to test whether we are on the first `ng-repeat` element (`$index` being which ng-repeat element we are currently on).  Like so

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" test-drive-step="$index === 0" ...>{{item.name}}</item>
```

And add it to your directive scope:

```
scope: { 
   test-drive-step: '=' 
},
```

So the directive can apply itself only if the attribute is `true`:

```
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
         if (scope.test-drive-step) 
            element.addClass('blue');  // Or whatever...
}
```

Here's a fiddle showing the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/6sc0acoa/2/

Comment: I had thought that could be an option, but I was wondering if there was another option.  But this is a good option too.  Thanks for posting.